# Typescript: Firebase App type missing delete, installations, name, options

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

I am new to Typescript and trying to make it work with Firebase. I have a FirebaseProvider that takes in a Firebase app configured in the following way:

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/analytics"
import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/firestore"
import "firebase/functions"
import "firebase/performance"

const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID
}

if (firebase.apps.length > 0) firebase.app()
else firebase.initializeApp(config)

export { firebase }
```

My apps entry point looks like:

```js
<FirebaseProvider firebase={firebase}>
  <App />
</FirebaseProvider>
```

I have the props for the `FirebaseProvider` declared as the following:

```js
interface FirebaseProviderProps {
  firebase: firebase.default.app.App
  children: ReactElement | ReactElement[]
}
```

However I am finding I get the following error:

```
Type 'typeof firebase' is missing the following properties from type 'App': delete, installations, name, options
```

What is the correct Firebase type for me to use? I have poked around in the SDK and can't seem any other types that seem relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've got the type for field `firebase` in `FirebaseProviderProps` as `app.App` but you've assigned to it the value in `firebase` which according to the code you've written is just a re-export of the default export (not the app):

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"

/* ... */

// this is just a re-export of the default export instead of an App
export { firebase }
```

```
{/* assigned the default export that was re-exported */}
<FirebaseProvider firebase={firebase}>
  <App />
</FirebaseProvider>
```

The type `app.App` though is the return value from either `firebase.app()` or `firebase.initializeApp(config)`.

So you could elect to export that instead:

```
let app: firebase.app.App;

if (firebase.apps.length > 0) {
  app = firebase.app();
} else {
  app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

// export that instead of 'firebase'
export { app }
```

And then pass that to your provider:

```
{/* assigned the default export that was re-exported */}
<FirebaseProvider firebase={app}>
  <App />
</FirebaseProvider>
```

At which point it would probably also make some sense to rename the prop:

```
{/* assigned the default export that was re-exported */}
<FirebaseProvider app={app}>
  <App />
</FirebaseProvider>
```

Comment: Legend! I can't believe I didn't see this. It has solved my issue, many thanks.